# RegEx for matching schema nesting

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to detect the nesting of one tag in another to raise an error.

Examples :

```
anything <amb id="1">word1</amb> anything <amb id="2">word2</amb> anything // OK

anything <amb id="1">anything<amb id="2">word2</amb>anything</amb> anything // KO
```

It is therefore necessary to detect the presence of tags `<amb...` or `</amb>` between the tags `<amb...` and `</amb>`

I have a beginning of a pattern, but I can't manage the nested presence of the tag.

```
// #\<amb(.*?)\<\/amb\># => OK : detect the first level
$pattern = '#\<amb(?!\<amb)\<\/amb\>#'; // KO

if(preg_match($pattern, $string)) {
  throw new Exception('No nested tags are allowed.');
}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: To match if nested another idea: [`<amb\b[^>]*>[^<]*(?:<(?!\/?amb\b)[^<]*)*<amb\b`](https://regex101.com/r/0wkHLe/2/)

Comment: XPath query `//amb//amb` would take care of this easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to check the nesting of tags is to check, if two continuous `<amb` tags are appearing without having a `</amb>` tag in between, then you can reject the string saying there is nesting of tags. This negative look ahead based regex should do the job,

```
^(?!.*<amb(?:(?!<\/amb).)+<amb).+$
```

**[Regex Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/jDPiGs/1)**

Similarly, another way is to check if two continuous `<\/amb>` tags appear without having a `<amb` tag in between, it means the tags are nested and again you can reject the string using this negative look ahead based regex,

```
^(?!.*<\/amb>(?:(?!<amb).)+<\/amb>).+$
```

**[Regex Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/DVDphd/1)**

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be working!
I didn't know how to write it in regex, and given the complexity, I wasn't ready to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions for this. [They are a pain](https://hackernoon.com/for-the-love-of-jeez-stop-using-regex-in-software-3a916e2c5987). What you can do is explode the string on `</amd>` and then check that each part has, at most, one `<amb` in it. Like so:

```
function correctlyNested($html, $tag)
{
    foreach (explode("</$tag>", strtolower($html)) as $part) {
       if (substr_count($part, "<$tag") > 1) return false; // it is KO
    }
    return true; // it is OK
}


$tests = ['anything <amb id="1">word1</amb> anything <amb id="2">word2</amb> anything',
          'anything <amb id="1">anything<amb id="2">word2</amb>anything</amb> anything'];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    echo $test . (correctlyNested($test, "amb") ? " // OK<br>" : " // KO<br>");
}
```

This code is easy to understand and maintain. I added the `strtolower()` to show how easy it is to extend this code.

Comment: Yes you're right, the use of a regex was not mandatory to solve the problem, but for reasons of homogeneity I preferred. Thanks anyway for your answer, it also works.